# You have to print all the numbers in the range from1 to N*N, such that there are exactly N numbers on each line

Tags: loops, nested

You have to print all the numbers in the range from1 to N*N, such that there are exactly N numbers on each line.
For example, if the value stored in N = 3, then all the numbers in the range, from [1,9] need to be printed, such that there are 3 numbers on each line. Therefore, the required output is

output
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Answer (score 0):

```
   function patternOfN(N){
    let a = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      let main = "";
      let prood = N * i;
      for (j = a; j <= prood; j++) {
        main = main + j + " ";
      }
      a = prood + 1;
      console.log(main);
    }
    }
    patternOfN(3);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let N = 3;

for (let i = 1; i <= N * N; i = i + N) {
    let bag = "";
    for (let j = I; j < i + N; j++) {
        bag += j + " ";
    }
    console.log(bag);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?